# primefaces input with tooltip button

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to create *input-field-attached-tooltip-button* (I don't quite know what to call it). Something like this:

[image: Example of what I want]

When you hoover over the question mark icon you see the help text.

Justification: The little icon makes it blatantly obvious that there's help attached to the field. You can see that help is indeed available without even moving the mouse pointer to the field. Gives the user this warm fuzzy feeling.

I cannot figure out how to do this in PrimeFaces.

I do not know which framework has produced the example above but I'm pretty sure it is not PrimeFaces.

I'm well aware of `<p:tooltip>` but I don't think it can do this.

Comment: I think `<p:overlayPanel>` could be part of the answer of how one would go about it if one was to create a custom solution from scratch. I was hoping for a more out-of-the-box solution. :-)

Comment: Just wrap it in a tagfile or perhaps composite.

Comment: Yes, but it will never become an integral part of the input field will it?  (bear with me, I'm not too good at this). If I put my fields inside a `<p:panelGrid>`> then how many columns would I need?  I'm hoping for something that only requires two columns: the label and the field. Some fields will have the help icon, others will not.

Comment: Just wrap input+help in another tagfile.

Comment: @BalusC.  Thank's. Got it !. I'll give it a shot and post here for those who wish to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's what I've come up with in PrimeFaces:

[image: My example]

(my screencapture does not show the mouse pointer)

I pretty much took BalusC's suggestions and created a JSF custom component. Here's what my custom component look like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">


    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="helptext"/>
        <composite:attribute name="show" />
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <p:button id="help" style="width: 15px; height: 15px" icon="ui-icon-help" rendered="#{cc.attrs.show}"/>
        <p:overlayPanel for="help" showEvent="mouseover" hideEvent="mouseout" hideEffect="fade" >
            <p:panel>
                #{cc.attrs.helptext}
            </p:panel>
        </p:overlayPanel>

    </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

and the xhtml that has produced the above screenshot looks like this:

```
<h:form>
    <p:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="noBorders">

        <p:outputLabel for="mydate" value="Date"  />
        <p:calendar id="mydate"  pattern="yyyy/MM/dd" />
        <customC:fieldhelp helptext="Help text for date field." show="true" />

        <p:outputLabel for="myboolean" value="Send now ?" />
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="myboolean" />
        <customC:fieldhelp helptext="Help text for boolean field." show="false"/>

        <p:outputLabel for="mypwd" value="Your password" />
        <p:password id="mypwd" size="30" />
        <customC:fieldhelp helptext="Help text for password field." show="true"/>

    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Seems to work fine. As you can see I had to reduce the size of the icon otherwise it would be way too big.

Some notes:

- The composite doesn't wrap both the help icon and the field. It only
  wraps the help icon. This has the downside that you'll need a three
  column layout and that the help icon is not displayed right next to
  the field. Instead it is displayed in its own column. Not exactly what I wanted.
- The help text is conveyed in an attribute. This has the downside that
  it cannot contain any HTML markup regardless of the fact that the
  destination, the `<p:panel>`, would happily accept HTML markup.
- You can leave out the help icon using the `show` attribute, however - 
  because of the three column layout - the `<customC:fieldhelp>` always 
  need to exist for each field. This is very clumsy but is again a result 
  of my lack of knowledge. :-(

I'm sure it can be improved upon if one knew a little more JSF/PrimeFaces than myself.

### EDIT

If you want the icon right next to the input field (rather than in a column of its own) then you'll need the `<h:panelGroup>` tag. You can wrap a group of elements in this tag and `<p:panelGrid>` (or its sibling : `<h:panelGrid>`) will then count it as a single element, i.e. occupies one cell only. Something like this:

```
<h:form>
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="noBorders">

        <p:outputLabel for="mydate" value="Date"  />
        <h:panelGroup>
            <p:calendar id="mydate"  pattern="yyyy/MM/dd" />
            <customC:fieldhelp helptext="Help text for date field." show="true" />
        </h:panelGroup>

        <p:outputLabel for="myboolean" value="Send now ?" />
        <h:panelGroup>
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="myboolean" />
            <customC:fieldhelp helptext="Help text for boolean field." show="false"/>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <p:outputLabel for="mypwd" value="Your password" />
        <h:panelGroup>
            <p:password id="mypwd" size="30" />
            <customC:fieldhelp helptext="Help text for password field." show="true"/>
        </h:panelGroup>

    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

In addition I had to do some CSS tweaking with `vertical-align: middle` to get the icon vertically aligned with the rest.

Comment: In case if you feel that the question-icon for every field makes the screen cluttered, you may consider this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194963/find-current-focused-component-id-to-show-online-contex-thelp